# Control-Command-Space opens Search

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

When I use the  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd> 
 <kbd>Space</kbd>  , It does not open the Emoji viewer, but opens a 'Search My Mac' in the Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that key combo hasn't been set up as a new command in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Spotlight

Default should be  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>

[image]

You could also check it wasn't added as a specific menu command in App Shortcuts...

[image]
...which would then show in the Finder's File menu too [together with a new 'Find By Name' item] compared to the original using  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>F</kbd>

[image] [image]